# Require.js and document.write()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs, blockly

I want to load a .js file asynchronously using require.js, but what I get is this error: 
    ***Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a     document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.***

The lines producing this error are at the very bottom of this file: https://code.google.com/p/blockly/source/browse/trunk/blockly_uncompressed.js?r=1234

So I tried a workaround:

```
var head = document.getElementById('head');
var myScript= document.createElement('script');
script1.innerHTML = "...";
head.appendChild(myScript);
```

This produces the error: ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addDependency' of undefined*** (line: 27)

How could I solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library you are trying to load is built to use the [Google Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/tutorial), which has its own module dependency system.  More specifically, what it's doing is:

1. Assuming that it is being loaded synchronously (running during page load).
2. Removing any existing GCL object that had been loaded.
3. Installing its own copy of GCL (loaded synchronously).
4. Configuring its self-installed GCL object for its purposes.

It accomplishes these steps by using `document.write` to create `<script>` tags.  Calling `document.write` while the page is still being loaded causes the written HTML to be appended to the page, whereas calling it after the page is done loading would overwrite the page.  If a script is loaded asynchronously, it creates a race condition between script load and page load, so the use of `document.write` in this situation is prohibited, and you get the error you saw:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

With your workaround, your code is loaded asynchronously, and the `<script>` tags created by the library are therefore also loaded asynchronously.  GCL load is initiated, but when it immediately tries to use GCL's `addDependency` function, it fails because GCL hasn't finished loading yet, and you get the error you saw:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addDependency' of undefined (line: 27)

Mixing GCL with RequireJS may be possible, but as you're seeing, it's going to be messy.  Since you have to use GCL for this library, you are probably better off just using GCL for everything.  If you can't do that, the following hack may work:

1. Load GCL with an ordinary `<script>` tag, synchronously, outside of RequireJS.
2. Copy the library code into your asynchronously-loaded module.
3. Replace the last three lines (the `document.write`s) with just: `window.BLOCKLY_BOOT();`